# A question in the proof of Counting Theorem

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to follow a proof but keep getting stuck. Here is the statement of the theorem...

Let $G$ be a finite group which acts on a set $X$. Let $X^g$ represent the subset of $X$ consisting of those points which are left fixed by the element $g$ of $G$. Then the number of distinct orbits is $$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|X^g|$$

...and here is the proof up to the point where I am lost.

Count the number of those ordered pairs $(g,x)$ from $G\times X$ for which $g\cdot x = x$. The number of such pairs is $$\sum_{g\in G}|X^g|$$ It is also equal to $$\sum_{x\in X}|G_x|$$ where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$. Let $X_1,...,X_k$ be the distinct orbits of $X$ (recall obits partition the underlying set) and rewrite $\sum_{x\in X}|G_x|$ as $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{x\in X_i} |G_x|$$ **Points in the same orbit have conjugate stabilizers, so if $\bar{x}$ is some point in $X_i$, we have** $$\sum_{x\in X_i}|G_x|=|X_i|\cdot |G_{\bar{x}}|$$

*Hic sunt leones*. The bold followed by the displayed equation makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain out the details to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fix some point $\bar{x} \in X_i$. Every point in $X_i$ has the form $x= g \bar{x}$ for some $g\in G$, because $X_i$ is an orbit. Now the stabilizer of $g\bar{x}$ is $G_{g\bar{x}} = g G_{\bar{x}} g^{-1}$ (exercise). In other words, the stabilizer of $g\bar{x}$ is conjugate to the stabilizer of $\bar{x}$. Since conjugate groups have the same order, every summand on the left is just $|G_{\bar{x}}|$, and the displayed equation follows.